# Taking only first two value out of grep -n

Tags: terminal, grep

so I'm using `lsusb | grep -n -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}'` to filter the data of my command inside my terminal. The thing is, I want to filter it even more and get the two specific rows that stands for a USB bus and device number.
Here is an output for example (in here I want to have the 002 and 001 from line 1 and 001 003 from line 2):

```
1:002
1:001
1:1
1:6
1:000
1:3
1:3
1:0
2:001
2:003
2:13
2:3
2:352
2:6
```

Can anyone tell me how to do so? plus if you have any easier way to get the value of the bus and device number out of the terminal using `lsusb` I'm open to suggestions.

lsusb:
lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 2b1d:2341 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 31d3:3125 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 31d3:67c1 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1245:1222 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1315:3232 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Would sed be a better choice than grep?

Comment: Or maybe awk, actually,

Comment: Yes awk is obvious choice but we need to see OP's expected output

Comment: Made some assumptions, but completely agree expected output would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk might be a better choice than grep here.

```
 lsusb | awk '{print $2" "substr($4, 1, length($4)-1)}'
```

Comment: or `lssub | awk -F '[:[:blank:]]+' '{print $2, $4}'`

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep`, you can get only numbers that follow `Bus` or `Device`:

```sh
grep -noP '(Bus|Device) \K\d+'
```

> I want to have the 002 and 001 from line 1 and 001 003 from line 2

Not very clear on this, but if you want only first two lines that match, you can use:

```sh
grep -m2 -noP '(Bus|Device) \K\d+'
```